# Timed out in SQL Conection

Tags: python, mysql, debian, mariadb

I using a code in python to synchronize data on SQL server in Amazon RDS (Maria DB).

When I run my code in Spider (windows) it works, but when I run in a board running debian, the connection returns timeout.

```
import mysql.connector

sqlConnRemoto = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', database='xxxx', host='xxxx.crmriwcyocxl.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', port = 3306, connection_timeout = 10)

sqlCurRemoto = sqlConnRemoto.cursor()
```

My server data (user, password, host....) is ok, because it works on windows. But did´not work on debian. What is the problem?

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 94, in **init**
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 722, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 207, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.crmriwcyocxl.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (timed out)

Comment: Are you running your Debian in a VM or different environment? If so, check your proxy settings.

Comment: I´m running in a BeagleBone Board. And I have successful connection for other server.

Comment: what does `telnet xxxx.crmriwcyocxl.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306` return

Comment: telnet xxxx.crmriwcyocxl.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306 return –

Trying 18.231.16.123...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out